# How to disable cron service delay on startup

Tags: linux, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to add the execution of a shell script on server startup. I do it using cron, so I configured it with 'crontab -e' command. It looks so:

```
@reboot /home/user/run.sh
```

Then I enabled service with

```
sudo systemctl enable cron.service
```

But when I reboot my server, jobs are not started. I check service status with:

```
sudo systemctl status cron.service
```

[screenshot with an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL4SO.png)

And there is a message that it's 2h 55min left to start executing all jobs. So, as I understood service is running but with 3 hours delay. It's happening after every server startup.

Using `sudo systemctl restart cron.service` command helps to make service working, but the server skips `@reboot` jobs because "it's not system startup".